# Can’t restore SQL Server 2000 backup to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have a backup file taken from a SQL Server 2000 database and I'm trying to restore it to a 2008 database. However, I'm getting this error:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo) The media family on device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\customers.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family. RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3241)

I am the one who originally took the backup (years ago). It was a hosted SQL Server. If I remember correctly, I got the backup using some sort of online "control panel"

Answer (score 3):

SQL 2000 SP4 database can be upgraded on-the-fly to SQL 2008 (including restore-upgrade). See [Version and Edition Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx). If you get that message most likely the media is corrupted.

Comment: What if the SQL 2000 was not SP4?  I don't know what SP it was.

Comment: Pre SP4 you need to upgrade it to the SP4 version first, by restoring it on a SQL 2000 SP4. SQL 2005 supports upgrade from SQL 7, so you can also try to restore it first on SQL 2005 (even Express), then on 2008. But as I say, most likely the backup is corrupted, otherwise you'd get a more specific error message about the supported version.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server 2008, follow these steps

1. Create New database with the same name as in SQL Server 2000
2. After writing database name, go to Options tab
3. In Compatibility Level dropdown select 'SQL Server 2000 (80)
4. After creating database, go to Task and select restore
5. After selecting restore resource go to options tab and select 'Overwrite the existing database (With Replace)
6. Your database will be restored